# Using a Groovy Enum as the Id field in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We have some legacy database mappings in GORM and several have a primary key which is an enumeration. The enumeration are stored using the string values, not the ordinals.

For example:

```
class AccountingGLMap {
    AccountingTypeCode id
    String typeCode

    static mapping = {
        id(column: 'accountingTypeCode',  generator: 'assigned')
    }
}
```

When you try to retrieve an instance, you get:

```
| Error 2012-02-23 10:32:41,319 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

I have verified that the values in the table map properly into the enumeration given (I can instantiate the object with the Enum so long as it's not the primary key). If we change the Enum to a String, everything works fine.

I did see an article claiming you can't use an Enum as the primary key when using JPA, but even that was disputed.

Anyone have experience doing this?

EDIT: For reference we are using 2.0.1 against an Oracle database.

Comment: I just tried to do this with Grails 1.3.7 using the in memory database and I had no problem. What version of Grails and what type of database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that, we are using 2.0.1 with Oracle. It only seems to break when the Enum is the key, otherwise the mapping works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `type: 'string'` to your id mapping and then add a setter for id that takes a String input like so:

```
class AccountingGLMap {
    AccountingTypeCode id
    GLTypeCode glTypeCode

    static mapping = {
        id(column: 'accountingTypeCode', type: 'string', generator: 'assigned')
    }

    void setId(String value) {
        id = value
    }
}
```